# ADSR in iOS, sample code?

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudioplayer, audiounit

I've been searching for some examples that show how to do [ADSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADSR_envelope#ADSR_envelope) in iOS using audio samples (preferably WAV files with loop points, but thats secondary). I guess most people who write a sampler/synth app use audio unit for this. Does any one know a good code example that shows ADSR in any iOS audio library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new iOS SDK 5.0 there's now a Sampler Audio Unit! Which can do ADSR envelopes.

The presets demo shows how to use the sampler:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011214

If you want to load different sound formats to play this article is helpful:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2283/_index.html

And here's the iOS documentation reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007291

Answer (score 1):

you can find (a very basic) one in the Apple's SinSynth sample. That is an AU, but it should demonstrate how one would apply a envelope to an audio buffer. i don't remember - it may simply be an ASR, but adding a fourth stage is simple once you have understood the existing program. The implementation is right in the note's render.

Envelope Generators are not platform specific.

[musicdsp.org](http://www.musicdsp.org/) will be a better resource if you want more than a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

MusicDSP has source code for an [example envelope follower](http://www.musicdsp.org/showone.php?id=136) with attack/release. If you understand this, then sustain/decay should be pretty logical. ;)

But an ADSR envelope is basically just a matter of applying gain to your output signal with a state machine. Each state has a starting value, and ending value, and a duration. Calculating the slope of that line and the value of each point along it was covered in your algebra class back in high school. ;) If you want to be really fancy, you can implement other types of curves, but the concept remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about using a state machine, that's what I though as well.